# JBehave - Passing parameters to parent stories

Tags: parameter-passing, jbehave

I am able to call few stories from a given story as they are pre-requisite for the current story to proceed. 
Want to know if there is anyway that I can pass the parameters to the parent stories from the current story.

Any inputs appreciated.

Comment: https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/given-stories.html -> GivenStories parametrized by Examples ?

Comment: Thanks for this Val.
I had looked into this and tried following it but things did not work as they were supposed to.

Looking for someone who can share any working example(s).

Comment: could you please provide your case which doesn't work? In my case GivenStories parametrization works fine